# Passing in an np array into pca.fit_transform

Tags: arrays, numpy, scikit-learn, pca

I'm trying to use PCA on data that is represented as an np array.

Here's my code so far:

```
def principal_components():
    pca = PCA(n_components=2)
    print type(windows(training_files))
    training_result = pca.fit_transform(windows(training_files))
    print type(training_result)
    testing_result = pca.transform(windows(test_files))
    return training_result, testing_result
```

The type of `windows(training_files)` is `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>` as is `windows(testing_files)`.

I get the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/saqibali/PycharmProjects/sensorLogProject/FeatureSelection/FeatureSelection.py", line 63, in <module>
principal_components()
File "/Users/saqibali/PycharmProjects/sensorLogProject/FeatureSelection/FeatureSelection.py", line 57, in principal_components
training_result = pca.fit_transform(list(windows(training_files)))
File "/Users/saqibali/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/sklearn/decomposition/pca.py", line 324, in fit_transform
U, S, V = self._fit(X)
File "/Users/saqibali/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/sklearn/decomposition/pca.py", line 346, in _fit
copy=self.copy)
File "/Users/saqibali/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 382, in check_array
array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How do I properly pass in an np array into PCA.fit_transform()? If I can't, how should I reformat my data to use PCA?

Here is `windows()`

```
def windows(files):
    x = []
    for my_files in files:
        df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['timestamp', 'time skipped', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'label']).set_index('timestamp')
        with open(os.path.join("/Users", "saqibali", "PycharmProjects", "sensorLogProject", "Data", my_files), 'rU')\
            as my_file:
            for d in sliding_window(sample_difference(my_file), 500, 250):
                df = df.append(d)
        x = np.append(x, df[['x', 'y', 'z']].values.tolist)
    return x
```

An example file is:

```
1501514704.745, 0, -0.055908, -0.729034, -0.645294, 3
1501514704.755, 0, -0.046158, -0.709091, -0.650177, 3
1501514704.765, 0, -0.036469, -0.699554, -0.672668, 3
1501514704.775, 0, -0.027908, -0.695740, -0.678070, 3
1501514704.785, 0, -0.027725, -0.678802, -0.697052, 3
1501514704.795, 0, -0.037491, -0.660660, -0.719605, 3
```

`sliding_window(sample_difference(my_file), 500, 250)` returns:

```
[                                      x         y         z
timestamp                                                  
1970-01-01 00:00:01.501514704 -0.055908 -0.729034 -0.645294
1970-01-01 00:00:01.501514704 -0.046158 -0.709091 -0.650177
1970-01-01 00:00:01.501514704 -0.036469 -0.699554 -0.672668
1970-01-01 00:00:01.501514704 -0.027908 -0.695740 -0.678070
.
.
.
timestamp                      x        y          z                                                  
1970-01-01 00:00:01.501514705  0.186447 -0.733322 -1.018127
1970-01-01 00:00:01.501514705  0.151810 -0.722305 -0.996490
1970-01-01 00:00:01.501514705  0.112946 -0.712280 -1.001602
1970-01-01 00:00:01.501514705  0.091904 -0.725403 -0.982437
```

The output of `x` is `[]`

The output of `df[['x', 'y', 'z']].values.tolist()` is:

`[[-0.055908000000000006, -0.729034, -0.6452939999999999], [-0.046158, -0.709091, -0.650177],  [-0.044601, -0.657684, -0.8261569999999999], [-0.022994999999999998, -0.6634979999999999, -0.8344879999999999], [-0.021896000000000002, -0.647369, -0.848801], [-0.0054020000000000006, -0.673096, -0.787338], [-0.99649], [0.112946, -0.71228, -1.001602]...`

Comment: Could you add a sample of windows(training_files) to your question?

Comment: I included it. Thanks

Comment: From a first look, in your windows function `x = np.append(x, df[['x', 'y', 'z']].values.tolist())` <-- missing parenthesis here - you are appending the `tolist` method itself, not the results.

Comment: When I do that I get `ValueError: Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(1, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required.` @mkaran

Comment: @dirtysocks45 Can you please tell me what `x`'s (or `df[['x', 'y', 'z']].values.tolist()`) value is? Also, what does `sliding_window(sample_difference(my_file), 500, 250)` return?

Comment: @mkaran I added the changes you wanted. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @dirtysocks45 The problem seems to be that x returns `[]`, but I am not sure why this happens. Can you check if the `training_files` has values and it enters the for loop `for my_files in files:` please?

Comment: If you try to append the output of `df[['x', 'y', 'z']].values.tolist()` to an array as you do, there are two reasons it will fail: (1) since you have sublists of different sizes, the array will have dtype `object` and will just contain the lists, instead of containing the numbers, and (2) since you are using append (without the `axis` arg) everything will be appended into the same row, creating a large 1D array. The PCA will interpret this as a single sample (with many features), which obviously won't work.

Comment: It is best to not ever use `np.append`. Instead, just use `x.append(df[etc])` to create a list of your data. Next, verify that your list `x` has a sensible structure (sublists must have identical size if your goal is to create a 2D array), then convert it to an array using `np.array(x)`.